# Protecting NSUserDefaults from user or third party intrusion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults

On OSX a user can delete NSUserDefaults either using the defaults utility or deleting the plist. See `man defaults`. Is there a way this can be monitored, considering the app would like to catch and take appropriate actions if the user or any malicious program does this. Deleting either way does not invoke `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` at all and hence cannot be used.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to secure settings, use the keychain. If you want to do so without incurring the pain and suffering of learning the keychain, there are several wrappers available that make string entries look like User Defaults.

Comment: On OSX even keychain data can be removed by the user. Some third party application can also remove it.

Comment: You may have to completely roll your own storage and monitoring then if you need that level of control. I suppose you could also go to the level of file monitoring of the plist using FSEvents.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things here: "if the user or any malicious program does this."

Regarding "if the user..." the answer is no. The user can do anything she wants. She can modify your program if she wants. It's her hardware. In order to prevent that, you have to develop effective DRM. You're not going to do that on top of `NSUserDefaults`. Apple can barely pull that off when they control every piece of the ecosystem. Basically, if you could solve this problem, Apple could use the same solution to prevent jailbreaks of iPhones.

If the idea is that you just want to obfuscate things a bit from the user, and aren't trying to deal with a motivated and skilled attacker, then `NSUserDefaults` is not the right tool. It has "user" right in the name. It's the *user's* stuff. Put your secret things in a hidden place. You'll have to come up with your own idea for that, since the only reason it would work at all is because it's a secret only you know. (This will be broken very quickly by a motivated attacker of course, but it will work for most of the users who any other system would work for; keep it simple.)

Regarding "any malicious program," that's a bit different, since you're protecting your *user* (a tractable problem) rather than trying to protect yourself *from* your user (an intractable problem). Storage in keychain would probably be a good choice. It has several built-in protections from malicious applications accessing it. You can also store your data on a server rather than on the box, which would protect against most malicious software (particularly assuming you sign your app, so malicious software can't modify it).

If what you're really trying to do is manage trials and licensing, there are several products on the market to help you obfuscate your keys, trial periods, etc. They spend their money developing and refining obfuscation and adapting as attackers break it. It's a full-time job. Unless you have a team to devote to it, I'd use one of the commercial products. It won't really fix your problem (those products are cracked all the time), but at least you can get back to real development.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not sensitive then save it using `NSUserDefaults`. It it is sensitive the use the keychain. <s>If you want to store information securely using `NSUserDefaults` (AES-356 bit encryption) then look into [SecureNSUserDefaults](https://github.com/nielsmouthaan/SecureNSUserDefaults)(I have colleagues that use this but I haven't had a need to myself).</s>

Otherwise, save your data (encrypted by your own means if you wish) using your own preferred data structure (dictionary or the like) to your app's documents folder.

Ultimately, anything that you store client side can be removed by the user. But you can try to stop it being deciphered and/or edited.

Comment: Do not use anything that claims to use ASE-356  bit encryption, there is not such thing. AES supports three key sizes: 128, 192 and 256 bits. SecureNSUserDefaults makes that claim. If you are going to use a 3rd party security library make sure it is well vetted and currently being maintained.